# Calcular edad en años, meses y dias en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola estoy haciendo un ejercicio en `android studio` para que el usuario al poner su fecha de cumpleaños le salga cuantos años, meses y días tiene a día de hoy.

Estoy utilizando la API 21 pero todas las formas que encuentro utilizan la API 26 para arriba

como pudiera hacerlo con la API 21?

Comment: Cuando preguntes Eduardo, no olvides agregar al menos lo que hayas tratado o investigado, ¿Que clase usaste?saludos!

Comment: Ok, gracias Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la libreria de Joda Time y utilizar el siguente codigo:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.Years;

LocalDate birthday = new LocalDate(1989, 12, 6);
LocalDate now = new LocalDate(2016, 10, 11);
Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthday, now);

System.out.println("age: " + age.getYears());  // prints "age: 26"
```

O tambien si usas Java 8 puedes usar:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1989, Month.DECEMBER, 6);
LocalDate now = LocalDate.of(2016, Month.OCTOBER, 11);

// using period
Period period = Period.between(birthday, now);
System.out.println(period.getDays());
System.out.println(period.getMonths());
System.out.println("age: " + period.getYears());  // prints "age: 26"

// using chrono unit
System.out.println("age: " + ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(birthday, now));  // prints "age: 26"
```

Viendo lo que tu OP requiere este metodo te puede funcionar:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String CURRDATE = "16-07-1991";
            String EFFDATE = "28-08-2018";

            Date startdate = null;
            Date enddate = null;
            try {
                startdate = formatter.parse(CURRDATE);
                enddate = formatter.parse(EFFDATE);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Calendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            startCalendar.setTime(startdate);

            Calendar endCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            endCalendar.setTime(enddate);

            int monthCount = 0;
            int firstDayInFirstMonth = startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            endCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -firstDayInFirstMonth + 1);

            while (!startCalendar.after(endCalendar)) {
                startCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                ++monthCount;
            }

            startCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            --monthCount;
            int remainingDays = 0;
            while (!startCalendar.after(endCalendar)) {
                startCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
                ++remainingDays;
            }

            startCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
            --remainingDays;

            int lastMonthMaxDays = endCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            if (remainingDays >= lastMonthMaxDays) {
                ++monthCount;
                remainingDays -= lastMonthMaxDays;
            }

            int diffMonth = monthCount % 12;
            int diffYear = monthCount / 12;
            int diffDay = remainingDays;

            System.out.println(diffYear + " Year(s) and " + diffMonth + " Month(s) and " + diffDay + " Day(s)");
```

27 Year(s) and 1 Month(s) and 12 Day(s)

Comment: El OP desea saber cuantos años, meses y días tiene a día de hoy, no solo la edad.

Comment: Espero que te sirva el ultimo fragmento de codigo q agregue. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

#### Obtener edad en años, meses y días a partir de la fecha de nacimiento, soportado para todas las versiones de APIs.

Como comentas, esto se puede realizar fácilmente usando la API 26, Android Oreo, mediante :

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
            LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of(1987, 2, 14);
            Period p = Period.between(birthdate, today);
            System.out.println("Tengo " + p.getYears() + " años, " + p.getMonths() + " meses, " + p.getDays() + " días de edad.");

        }
```

Para APIs anteriores a 26 puedes realizarlo simplemente utilizando las clases `Calendar` y `Date`, mediante este método:

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(1987,2,14);
        Calendar c1 =  new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

        long end = c2.getTimeInMillis();
        long start = c1.getTimeInMillis();

        long milliseconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(Math.abs(end - start));
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1970;
        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1;
       
        System.out.println("Tengo " + mYear + " años, " + mMonth + " meses, " + mDay + " días de edad.");
```

Puedes usar el método el cual recibe el año, mes y día de nacimiento y te entrega tu edad en años, meses y días :

```
public static String getAge(int yearOfBirth, int monthOfBirth, int dayOfBirth) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of(yearOfBirth, monthOfBirth, dayOfBirth);
        Period p = Period.between(birthdate, today);
        return "Tengo " + p.getYears() + " años, " + p.getMonths() + " meses, " + p.getDays() + " días de edad.";
    }else{
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(yearOfBirth,monthOfBirth,dayOfBirth);
        Calendar c1 =  new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        
        long end = c2.getTimeInMillis();
        long start = c1.getTimeInMillis();

        long milliseconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(Math.abs(end - start));

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1970;
        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1;

        return "Tengo " + mYear + " años, " + mMonth + " meses, " + mDay + " días de edad.";
    }
}
```

Un ejemplo de como llamar este método :

```
System.out.println("Edad => " + getAge(1985,2 ,14));
```

entregará como salida:

```
Edad => Tengo 33 años, 6 meses, 16 días de edad.
```